# Save Button | note application

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I'm having trouble adding a `Button` to save text input in my `editorActivity` class, which is an `Activity` I designated to view, edit, and save a note item.

The class uses the back button (hardware) and app launcher icon to save the `key/value` pair to a `SharedPreferences` object. I want to add a `Button` that will do the same.

I get an error in the console stating:

```
res\layout\activity_note_editor.xml:18: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/Save').
```

I'm not sure what this implies. And would appreciate some guidance as to where I should to fix this error.

This is what I have so far:

```
private NoteItem note;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);                  // Load custom note edit layout
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);          // Launcher icon becomes an options button = home

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();           // Reference to intent object in first activity
    note = new NoteItem();
    note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));  // retrieve key and saved in note object
    note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));    // Retrieve text and save in note object

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    et.setText(note.getText());
    et.setSelection(note.getText().length());
}

private void saveAndFinish() {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    String noteText = et.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());      
    intent.putExtra("text", noteText);  
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}

@Override                   // launcher icon sends data back to main activity
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {            
        saveAndFinish();
    }
    return false;                                           
}

@Override                       // device back button sends data back to main activity
public void onBackPressed() {
    saveAndFinish();
}

public void addListenerOnButton(){

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveAndFinish();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't *imply* anything, it *explicitly* states that the [string resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) you're accessing doesn't exist. Create it.

Comment: @323go He apparently doesn't understand how to create it whether he missed that section of the tutorial he's following or somehow missed it in the docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure what this implies.

It implies that you don't have a `resource` in your `strings.xml` with the identifier of "Save"

When you use `@String`, or @anyAndroidResource for that matter, it looks in the corresponding file. So `@drawable` would look inside the `drawables` folder for whatever identifier you used.

In `values/strings.xml` you should have something like

```
<string name="Save">Save</string>
```

[Resources Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

[Resources Overview Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html)

Comment: Thanks @codeMagic. I created the resource in the strings.xml file. Now I'm having trouble with the syntax for the onClickListener method call. I get a syntax error for the onBackPressed method preceding my onClickListener method. The ide is telling me to delete the closing "}" for the onBackPressed method. I'm not sure why it's telling me to delete if it needs the closing "}".

Comment: This is my new onClickListener method code:                      `final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         button.setText("Saved!");
         saveAndFinish();
        }
    });
}`

Comment: @LuisFelipe That's a different issue and needs to be in its own post so it is more clear for others and you would need to post more detail because that little bit looks ok to me. What I will say is make sure that code is inside of a method.